# Problem with webpack 5 historyApiFallback

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

During migration from Webpack 4 to 5 I'm stuck with this weird case.

I have next dev config:

```
    ...
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.tsx")
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "dist/bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    devtool: "eval-cheap-source-map",
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        host: "localhost",
        port: 1337,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: path.resolve(__dirname, "./templates/index.dev.html"),
        },
        proxy: {
            "/report": {
                target: "http://localhost:8110",
            },
        },
        static: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
    },
    ...
```

and the following project structure:

[image]

`index.dev.html` contains script with `dist/bundle.js` source, so basically I'm about to serve it as an application entrypoint for browser.

The running script is:

```sh
cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=webpack/tsconfig.json CONFIG=development webpack-dev-server --config webpack/config.ts
```

Basically what happens:
On dev server start I'm getting following messages that seem right:

> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Proxy created: /report  -> http://localhost:8110
>  [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
>  [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:1337/, http://127.0.0.1:1337/
>  [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'C:\Users<path to project root>' directory
>  [webpack-dev-server] 404s will fallback to 'C:\Users<path to project root>\webpack\templates\index.dev.html'

Since it has been started, bundle is successfully served from `localhost:1337/dist/bundle.js`, `localhost:1337/report` redirects correctly, any `/static` requests are serving content from `static` folder, but everything else results with 404.

For example

- `http://localhost:1337/dist/bundle.js` serves application bundle
- `http://localhost:1337/report` goes to `http://localhost:8110/report` successfully
- `http://localhost:1337/static/images/add-icon.png` returns corresponding image from `static` folder
- `http://localhost:1337` returns (with 404)

> Cannot GET /

- `http://localhost:1337/edit/10` returns (with 404)

> Cannot GET /edit/10

Obviously, 404 fallback is not working. Same config worked perfectly on Webpack 4, the problem appeared only in Webpack 5. The only difference in config is that for 4 version there was `contentBase` instead of `static`, but commenting out this line not solving the problem.

What I'm doing wrong? I saw couple of simillar questions, but none of them were answered. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem two days ago and [this](https://ui.dev/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh) article helped me. All very clearly explained. It worked like a charm for me.
If you don't want to go into details, change `historyApiFallback: { index: path.resolve(__dirname, "./templates/index.dev.html") }` to `historyApiFallback: true` in your configuration.

Comment: This works, but only like a workaround, because HtmlWebpackLoader should be used in dev config to make things work. The problem is that my config was made according to official docs, and theoretically anything should be fine (startup logs of Webpack also confirm that), but for some reason it still does not work. So I'm thinking whether it is a bug or not.